# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

Анализ выполнен в диапазоне вероятных размеров частиц от 0,1 до 1000 мкм с использованием
зеленого и красного лазеров с последующим автоматическим объединением исследованных интервалов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятых здесь не надо, но вместо "с последующим" я бы советовал написать "и последующим"

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, запятые должны стоять после слов "частиц", "мкм".